# inputの検索履歴一覧表示について

Tags: monaca

お世話になっております。
下記画像のような、inputの検索履歴の一覧表示をmonacaで実装された方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。
もしくはこんな方法はどう？等共有いただけると非常にありがたいです。

[image: 参考画像]

Answer (score 2):

HTML5のSuggestを使用するのが一番の近道かと思います。

1. 検索時にWebDatabase(SQLite)を使用して検索履歴を保存する。
2. 検索フォームの初期化時にDBからデータを取得し、`datalist`タグでデータリストを作成する。
3. `list`要素で`datalist`を指定し、HTML5の`suggest`機能を使用し検索履歴を表示する。

```js
//検索履歴配列
var history_list = [];

function fake_search(){
  //検索語を取得しクリア
  var sword = $("#s_words").val();
  $("#s_words").val("");
  
  //既に登録した語句でなければ追加
  if(0>$.inArray(sword, history_list)){
    //Suggestに履歴を追加
    $("#search_history").append($("<option>").val(sword));
    //単語リストに追加
    history_list.push(sword);
  }
  
  alert("擬似検索しました。\n検索履歴に語句を追加しました。");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="s_words" name="s_words" placeholder="検索語を入力してください。" list="search_history" />
<button onclick="fake_search();">検索</button>
<datalist id="search_history">
</datalist>
```

※上記例は手っ取り早くするためにjQueryを使用しています。